# pymongo find() vs mongodb find(), pymongo find() gives less data about document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a `partner collection` and I am using `pymongo` to retrieve the data
When I query the collection with **MongoDB**, I see the following result

```
db.partner.find({'unique_key': 'c89dbe313932008febde61cdd2a071a1d'},{})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4eb463cb158acb554e8c9c11"), "unique_key" : "c89dbe313932008febde61cdd2a071a1d", "name" : "ABC", "primary_key" : 12 }
```

But when I query via **pymongo**, here is what I do

```
for document in collection.find(find, criteria):
    print document  

where find = {'unique_key': 'c89dbe313932008febde61cdd2a071a1d'} and
      criteria = {}
```

Here is what I see in result:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('4eb463cb158acb554e8c9c11')}
```

and I don't get **name** and **primary_key** in result, am I missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that when you pass empty dictionary (your `criteria` variable) as the second parameter it means you want no fields returned (except `_id` that is always returned). The second parameter for `find()` defines the fields that you want. Try to set `criteria=None` or not pass `criteria` at all.

[Link](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) to the pymongo document for `find()`.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to how the mongodb shell interprets `{}` as a field selector vs. how pymongo interprets an empty dictionary. In essence, the shell ignores the empty object as a field selector, whereas pymongo is interpreting it as "return nothing (except the default of `_id`)".

You don't need to specify a field selector when using pymongo or the mongodb shell (you can just leave it blank). Thus, this statement in the shell:

```
db.partner.find({'unique_key': 'c89dbe313932008febde61cdd2a071a1d'},{})
```

is equivalent to:

```
db.partner.find({'unique_key': 'c89dbe313932008febde61cdd2a071a1d'})
```

(this statement will work in both the shell and pymongo)